# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 captive portal

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

**Hi guys,
I have to make a captive portal for a school project with some friends. One of us got it working and we basically copied the image from his Raspberry PI to our Raspberry PI. After we did that, everything seems to be fine but then suddenly when we open our Captive Portal and try to log in with the username and password which we have saved in the database, this appears:**

HTTP Status 500 - captiveportal/proccess : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class captiveportal.proccess)

type Exception report

message captiveportal/proccess : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class captiveportal.proccess)

description The server encountered an internal error (captiveportal/proccess : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class captiveportal.proccess)) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: captiveportal/proccess : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class captiveportal.proccess)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2905)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1170)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:461)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.28 logs.

**We basically need to fill in the username and the password and after that we should be able to use the internet but unfortunately this error appears.
Did somebody have got the same error before? I am not sure what to do, I kept searching for straight 2 days but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer.
I hope you guys can help me with this problem, thanks in advance.
Empaier.**

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Comment: /hosting/apps/java/jre_1/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"

I have compiled with 1.8 and deployed on tomcat running 1.7..Got same issue

Answer (score 4):

What it means is that , your code is compiled with different version of java to java version which is running it .
make sure you compile and runt it with the same version if java.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are compiling your files with java 1.8 but the server where you are running them runs with an older java version.

Either run server with java 1.8 or compile your code with a target version equivalent to the jre running your server.

Check the runtime environment of server in eclipse

1. From the Window menu, select Preferences.
2. In the Preferences window, expand the Server folder and then select Runtime Environments.
3. select the server you are using
4. click edit button
5. Then check out the execution environment (check the java version(1.8) is correct or not)

check project compiler also

1. Right click your eclipse project
2. Take properties
3. click java compiler
4. Check the java compiler version is the same (1.8)

Thank you