# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class)

Tags: java

When i run my project i am getting the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: apache/commons/codec/UtilityUtil : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class apache.commons.codec.UtilityUtil)
```

I have researched and found out that it happens if the version of java is different from runtime and compilation time.

I have followed these two posts and tried to figure out that i am using java 8 and runtime has 1.7.:
[Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 captive portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344534/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-captive-portal)
[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

I have changed the compilation version to 1.7. But still the same problem exists. I dont know why.

Runtime version: 1.7.0_45
Compilation Version: 1.7.0_80.

Comment: as others noted, if you're compiling the codec library make sure the build sets targetCompatibility to be 1.7. On the other hand, if you're consuming the codec library as is (from Maven Central for example, or other binary repository) then the only thing you can do is upgrade your runtime to Java8 as you can't change the compiled binary.

Comment: I am pretty sure i am using java 1.7 but just to confirm is there a way to see the version of compilation used for the built?

i confirmed i am using 1.7 by seeing: project--> properties-->java build path(made sure using jre 1.7)

project-->properties-->Java Compiler (1.7) Here. @aalmiray

Comment: The problem may not be on your compiler setup but in the binaries you're consuming as dependencies. Check the Apache codec dependency with https://github.com/zeroturnaround/bad-classes. If it tells you it uses 52 (Java8 most likely based on the exception) then you either run your code with 1.8 _or_ download a copy of Apache Codec in source and compile it with 1.7 if possible, then set it as a dependency on your project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a duplicate. The classes you are using are probably compiled with Java 1.8 and your jvm is 1.7. That also includes 3rd party jars

Comment: I have made a re build and deployed the latest into server. So all the classes must compile using the latest version right?

Comment: Wooops, sorry for my answer! you were faster than me :) +1

Comment: But third party jars are not rebuilt

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.Sorry for asking you this, but how do i rebuild third party files @efekctive.

Comment: Hi @efekctive. You are correct. I have used echo to print the java version while building.It printed :
  [echo]  Java/JVM version: 1.8
     [echo]  Java/JVM detail version: 1.8.0_73.

I am not really sure how to change that to 1.7 :( as i ahve changed the compilation version to 1.7 and removed the JRE 8 and included jre 7.

Answer (score 2):

52 = J2SE 8. You are still compiling with Java 1.8 (or some libs you are using are compiled with 1.8 as pointed out by @efekctive).

Please post what command are you using to build.

Answer (score 2):

As @efekctive stated my build is using java 8 for building the class. Changed the version back to 7 and worked as expected. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Please do the following steps to find out yourJRE version and JDK version.

### JRE check

java -version

java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-2~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)

### JDK check

javac -version

javac 1.6.0_38

And you can find that both the versions are different. So, make them into common version. That will solve your issue.